# Disable duplicate WC product category URLs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WC generates duplicate URLs when using category slugs.

Example: demoshop.com/cat-1/product-a

The same product can be accessed from any URL if slug "cat-1" is modified, e.g.: demoshop.com/modified/product-a will lead to a status code 200 as well.

From a SEO perspective this is not preferrable and I would like to modify the behaviour as follows: If the product page is accessed via the correct url a 200 is sent. If the product page is accessed via any other url a 301 to the correct url is sent.

If the product has muliple categories assigned, the primary one should be considered.

Based on an idea in wordpress.org forum I try to resolve the issue by comparing the url requested by user with the "original" url:

```
   global $wp;
   $browser_url = add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars, home_url( $wp->request ) );
   // Should store complete url in variable but stores domain only

   global $post;
   $cat_slug = // Still looking for a solution to get primary product category for current product and to store primary category slug in variable
```

Still stuck with above code part.
Any hints are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To get the parent category slug you can use `get_ancestors`.

First check if the current opbject is for a taxonomy:

```
if ( is_tax() ){
    $current_term = get_queried_object()->term_id;
}
```

Once you are able to get the current term, use `get_ancestors()`.

```
$ancestors = get_ancestors( $current_term, 'example_category' ); // 2nd param is tax name
```

`get_ancestors()` will return an array which you can then reverse to get the main / primary parent.

```
if ( $ancestors && is_array( $ancestors ) ) {
    $ancestors = array_reverse( $ancestors );
    $ancestor  = $ancestors[0];
}
```